# Existence of subsequence $\{n_k\}$ tending to infinity such that $P(\cap_k A_{n_k}>0)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

[image]

I started this year to study probability and I'm using *A Probability Path* of Resnick, I'm trying to solve this exercise but I can't see the link between the Borel-Cantelli's Lemma that I studied and the exercise.
Can someone help me and give a Hint for the second question too?

Comment: Can you state the Borel-Cantelli lemma as you've seen it?

Comment: Let {An} be any events. If the summation of P(An)< +infinity then P([An i.o.]) = P([limsup An]) = 0

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$,  $\mathbb{P}(A^c_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Set $A_{n_1}=A_1$. Once $A_{n_1},\ldots,A_{n_k}$ ($n_1<\ldots<n_k$) have been selected, let  $A_{n_{k+1}}$ so that $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and $\mathbb{P}(A^c_{n_{k+1}})\leq\frac12\mathbb{P}(A^c_{n_k})$. Then 
$$\sum_k\mathbb{P}(A^c_{n_k})<\infty$$
an so, $\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_k\bigcup_{m\geq k}A^c_{n_m}\Big)=0$. Thus $\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_k\bigcap_{m\geq k}A_{n_m}\Big)=1$ and (a) follows.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to provide some minimal hints to get you un-stuck. There's still a fair bit to do after these hints; please let me know if you need more help.

(a) Consider the complementary events, $A_n^c$, for which $\mathbb P(A_n^c) \to 0$. This isn't enough to guarantee that $\sum \mathbb P(A_n^c) < \infty$, but you can argue that it has a *subsequence* that has this property. (How?)

(b) Let $\Omega = (0, 1)$, and let $$A_n = \{x \in (0,1) : \text{the binary representation of $x$ has a 1 in its $n^{\text{th}}$ position}\}.$$ Note that $\mathbb P(A_n) = 1/2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes thanks, now i understand how to do (b), but still not (a)

Comment: Can you argue that such a subsequence exists? If so, what property does the complementary subsequence have?